# Samsung Galaxy SII: OTA ROM Manager update to CyanogenMod: Verification Failed

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s-2, rom, rom-flashing, rom-manager

Howdi,

Basically as question says;

Download and Install Cyanogenmod 7.1.0 from ROMManager App, reboot into system recovery, and lo and behold

```
E:failed to verify whole-file signature
E:signature verification failed
Installation aborted.
```

Also tried with the 'standard' download from the website instead of OTA, same issue even after verifying md5 hash

**Anyone got any ideas?**

Comment: What recovery do you have installed? Did you disable signature verification in your recovery (whatever kind it may be, but guessing ClockworkMod if you're using ROM Manager)?

Answer (score 1):

I'd try putting the "standard download" on your device at `/sdcard/update.zip` and manually flashing it without using ROM Manager (reboot into recovery and select it yourself).  RM doesn't always play nice with Samsung devices.

Comment: If you are using Clockwork Recovery, do not use "/sdcard/update.zip", clockwork keeps a file of that name to reinstall if needed. Use something else and select 'Select package from SDCard' (or something like that). If you don't have that option, then you do not have clockwork recovery installed, or it is not booting to clockwork, try reinstalling clockwork recovery from ROM Manager.